# HashMap as return value from Java method in R?

Tags: java, r

Is it possible to return a HashMap to R with the rJava extension of R?
E.g. I have a method in Java, which returns a HashMap and I want this HashMap use in R. I tried:

```
.jcall(javaObj, "Ljava/util/HashMap", "getDbInfoMap")
```

This doesn't work.
Do I have to put everything into a String[], that I want to pass to R from Java?
Or is there another possibility?

Any help/info on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a GNU Project, which is similar to S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon when specifying the `HashMap` return type.

```
.jcall(javaObj, "Ljava/util/HashMap;", "getDbInfoMap")
```

See [JNI Types Field Descriptors](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html#70113) and [examples of .jcall](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/).